# Get a previous order number WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am trying to get previous order number from the specified order number for example there are 5 orders we have.
1780
1781
1782
1784
1786
Now if i specifiy the order number

wc_custom_get_previous_order_number(1784)

I should get 1782. I have tried multiple solutions. For example :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'custom_woocommerce_order_number', 1, 2 );
function custom_woocommerce_order_number( $oldnumber, $order ) {
  $lastorderid = $order->id-1; // here is i am trying to get previous order number.
// other code...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your own function with a SQL query with 2 arguments:

- `$order_id` is the starting order ID.
- `$limit` is the number of orders Ids to get from.

The function code:

```
function get_orders_from( $order_id, $limit = 1 ){
   global $wpdb;

    // The SQL query
    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT ID
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
        WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND ID < $order_id
        ORDER BY ID DESC
        LIMIT $limit
    " );
    return $limit == 1 ? reset( $results ) : $results;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

**USAGE** *(examples)*:

1) To get the previous order ID from the current `$order_id` you will use in your code:

```
$previous_order_id = get_orders_from( $order_id );
```

You will get directly the previous order ID…

2) To get the 3 previous orders IDs from order ID 1784:

```
// Get the array of orders_ids
$orders_ids = get_orders_from( 1784, 3 );

// Converting and displaying a string of IDs (coma separated)
echo implode( ', ', $orders_ids );
```

You will get: `1780, 1781, 1782`

Comment: Yes it is for sure :)